# EF 4.1 Null inserted GUID which is not null

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1

I keep getting this error :

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table
>   'database.dbo.Employees'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

But the object has this property set with `Guid.NewGuid()`

I use Entity Framework 4.1 and .net framework 4.0.

The column is primary key and not null. I'm not using Code First approach.

Edit : it seems that the Run Custom tool won't update the file if I edit manually the file edmx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if you have marked the key property as an autogenerated identity in your model with Fluent API or data annotations...

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

... (which has the effect that EF won't send the `Id` value to the database because it expects that the key is generated there) but in your database table you didn't specify that the default value for the `Id` column is `newid()` so that the database doesn't generate a new key.

I you want to send the `Guid` value manually from the client to the database remove the `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` specification from your model.

Comment: I found the problem, but your suggested answer wasn't the problem.

Comment: i'll give +1 for the fact you teach me something new in EF. But it seems that if i manually edit the file the run custom tool won't work on updating the entities correctly

Answer (score 0):

The problem which caused the error was that the *Run Custom tool* didn't completely update the the entities. The insert from SQL worked so I tried revert from changes Slauma suggested and other changes from entities.